# How to protect a .SO file from being copied/pirating?

Tags: static-libraries, copy-protection

I have developed an algorithm for android device and want to release the .SO file of my algorithm to other develop company.
How can I protect the .SO file from being copied/pirating? For example, add use time limitation on it. Is there some software can do it?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use static library instead? it will be linked into end-binary without separate file